# Drupal 7 using webform Calculator module

Tags: drupal

I have to create a calculator that calculate some values in text fields and shows the result. User is able to see that result as a bar graph or column graph. 
Example: https://sonomacleanpower.org/drive-ev-choose-ev

I have created a calculator and it is working fine.

Is there a way I can represent the text fields values as bar chart or a graphical representation using Drupal modules?

Comment: Had you build this calculator functionality as drupal module ?
If yes, you can add high chart libraries inside your module and use events of high chart to display this king of bar chart over your calculator result.

Comment: Thank you I have used a web from calculator module to build this calculator. Can I use Charts module in Drupal 7 to implement this functionality?